# Where does Javascript allocate memory for the result of a function call? Stack or heap?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have looked all over the internet and I can't seem to find an answer to this question.

- I read that the stack is used to store primitives and heap is for objects.
- I also read that the stack's size is fixed and once allocated it does not change, hence why it's used for primitives, because JS knows the size of each variable before runtime.
- I also know that primitives are immutable, so if we try to reassign a variable, it will not change the value at its memory address but will rather allocate new space in memory, store the new value and assign its address to the variable.

If the above is correct, then what happens when I do this?

```
let string = "Hello World"; // Memory allocated for "Hello World"
string = string.ToUpperCase(); // New memory allocated for "HELLO WORLD"
```

Where does the new memory for HELLO WORLD get allocated? Is it in the stack because it's a primitive? Or is it in the heap because JS does not know its value until it runs the code?

If it's in the stack, what happens to the old "Hello World" then? Since only the heap is garbage collected does that mean that the old, unused, string will stay there until the program finishes running?

What happens if I do

`string = string.repeat(10000000000)`

If the stack can't grow, does it mean that at some point I can stack overflow because a variable is too large?

Thank you.

Comment: There is neither _the stack_ nor _the heap_. A callstack (there can be multiple at the same time) will always have _fixed size values_ (not all the same size), because when accessing variables you want to be able to calculate the memory location easily (you don't want to search through the stack for each value). For numbers putting them onto the stack is easy (64bit size, maybe less), for strings it is not, as their size is usually not known. The engine could put it onto the stack if it statically knows the size.

Comment: Also in theory one could use a growing stack, but you'd usually not need that, and in case of infinite recursion it makes more sense to crash the program early than to run till the computer runs out of memory. That's why callstacks are usually fixed size.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "There is neither the stack nor the heap"...  The fact that you wrote "could put it" in your last sentence makes me think that the engine could take different actions, depending on the specific case which matches with what t-j-crowder wrote in his answer. Thank you!

Comment: @EccTama - There can be multiple stacks, and multiple heaps, so "the" really should be "a".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer may vary by engine, and it really doesn't matter to your code.** Worry about running out of stack if/when you run out of stack. JavaScript's specification doesn't require implementations to do one thing or the other. It describes behavior, not the implementation of that behavior.

But speaking practically: It seems unlikely that a JavaScript engine would try to put a massive string on the stack. More likely, it would put it in the heap. That doesn't mean it can't put *other* strings on the stack. Maybe it decides based on size. Maybe it decides based on lifetime — perhaps it'll put a small string used only locally in a function on the stack, but put a massive one, or one retained globally, on the heap.

The point is: Modern JavaScript engines are complicated and highly, highly optimized. They're unlikely to take such a simplistic view as "primitives go on the stack and objects go on the heap."

> I read that the stack is used to store primitives and heap is for objects.

Not necessarily. Objects can be allocated on the stack as well, and have been by at least some JavaScript engines at various points in history. If an object won't survive the end of the function call, and isn't massive, putting it on the stack makes reclaiming it when the function returns dead easy.

> I also know that primitives are immutable, so if we try to reassign a variable, it will not change the value at its memory address but will rather allocate new space in memory, store the new value and assign its address to the variable.

Without getting too deep into theory, again this could well be implementation-specific. Consider `a = 1`. We have no way of telling whether that puts the value `1` in the memory associated with `a`, or puts a reference to an immutable singleton representing `1` in `a`. The former seems more **a lot** more likely than the latter (for numbers; strings are another matter), but we don't know and can't know (in the general case; we can for a specific version of a specific engine), because it makes no difference to our code and the spec doesn't require one behavior or the other.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I didn't know the engine could "decide" to deal with values of the same type in different ways depending on the case. Most resources online just divide it in primitives = stack, non-primitives = heap which, after reading your answer, feels a little too simplistic. It makes a little more sense now. Thank you.

Comment: This is by far the best and clearest answer to this interesting topic I've read so far. Coming from Java (and a little bit of C++), I am used to having a clear mental model of memory management (at least spec-wise). So I guess thinking of a simple implementation, like the classic memory models of Java/C++ probably make the most sense to work with the language. Would you agree?

Comment: @tweekz - Thanks! I came from C (and a bit of C++) and Java as well. I can't speak to modern C++ (haven't written any in nearly 30 years, when it was quite a different language), but I wouldn't say Java and JavaScript had particularly similar memory models. JavaScript uses closures as a really fundamental concept, vs. the relative bolt-on aspect of anonymous classes in Java (and later, lambda syntax for creating them). I *suspect* that affects how the runtime engines manage memory. I find it more useful to think about the lexical environment objects that (conceptually) hold bindings and how...

Comment: ...closures reference them. The only time I even begin to think about stack vs. heap is when I'm potentially passing a **lot** of arguments to a function (like, more than 30k of them, which is roughly the limit in at least one modern engine), for instance with an operation like `someArray.push(...someIterable)` where I don't know for sure how large `someIterable` may be. And that's just because I want to avoid overflowing the stack. Hope that helps in some way!